# Computing the decision boundary of a linear SVM model

Tags: machine-learning, svm

Given the support vectors of a linear SVM, how can I compute the equation of the decision boundary?

Comment: w = sum over i (ai ti xi). you will have to minimize the lagrangian to find the values of the multipliers, ai. i wonder how u got the support vectors ? the same process should also give u the value of ai's.

Comment: I cannot comment yet but I think in the accepted answer shouldn't the decision line and margins be: abline(b/w[2],-w[1]/w[2]) abline((b+1)/w[2],-w[1]/w[2],lty=2) abline((b-1)/w[2],-w[1]/w[2],lty=2) since abline takes input as intercept and slope respectively? w.x-b=0 **which implies:** w1.x1+w2.x2=b **which implies(since x2 is the "y")** abline(b/w[2], -w[1]/w[2]) Sorry this is an old post but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Nepze Tyson. This isn't an answer to the OP's question. Please only use the "Your Answer" field to provide answers. If you have your own question, click the `[ASK QUESTION]` at the top of the page & ask it there, then we can help you properly. Since you are new here, you may want to read our [tour page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/about), which contains information for new users.

Comment: @Nepze Thank you for your perceptive comment and for the time and attention you took in order to make it.  I expect it will lead to an improved answer here.  I would also like to join gung in welcoming you to our site.

Comment: @dshin: see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164935/how-to-calculate-decision-boundary-from-support-vectors/167245#167245

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/), from Hastie et al., has a complete chapter on support vector classifiers and SVMs (in your case, start page 418 on the 2nd edition). Another good tutorial is [Support Vector Machines in R](http://www.ci.tuwien.ac.at/~meyer/svm/final.pdf), by David Meyer.

Unless I misunderstood your question, the decision boundary (or hyperplane) is defined by $x^T\beta + \beta_0=0$ (with $\|\beta\|=1$, and $\beta_0$ the intercept term), or as @ebony said a linear combination of the support vectors. The margin is then $2/\|\beta\|$, following Hastie et al. notations.

From the on-line help of `ksvm()` in the [kernlab](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kernlab/index.html) R package, but see also [kernlab – An S4 Package for Kernel Methods in R](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v11/i09/paper), here is a toy example:

```
set.seed(101)
x <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(120),,2),matrix(rnorm(120,mean=3),,2))
y <- matrix(c(rep(1,60),rep(-1,60)))
svp <- ksvm(x,y,type="C-svc")
plot(svp,data=x)
```

Note that for the sake of clarity, we don't consider train and test samples.
Results are shown below, where color shading helps visualizing the fitted decision values; values around 0 are on the decision boundary.

[image]

Calling `attributes(svp)` gives you attributes that you can access, e.g.

```
alpha(svp)  # support vectors whose indices may be 
            # found with alphaindex(svp)
b(svp)      # (negative) intercept
```

So, to display the decision boundary, with its corresponding margin, let's try the following (in the rescaled space), which is largely inspired from a tutorial on SVM made some time ago by [Jean-Philippe Vert](http://cbio.ensmp.fr/~jvert/):

```
plot(scale(x), col=y+2, pch=y+2, xlab="", ylab="")
w <- colSums(coef(svp)[[1]] * x[unlist(alphaindex(svp)),])
b <- b(svp)
abline(b/w[1],-w[2]/w[1])
abline((b+1)/w[1],-w[2]/w[1],lty=2)
abline((b-1)/w[1],-w[2]/w[1],lty=2)
```

And here it is:

[image]

Comment: Beautiful, exactly what I was looking for.

The two lines:

w <- colSums(coef(svp)[[1]] * x[unlist(alphaindex(svp)),])
b <- b(svp)

were a godsend.  Thank you!

Comment: @chi: it may be interesting to take a look at my answer to "how to compute the decision boundary of an SVM": http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164935/how-to-calculate-decision-boundary-from-support-vectors/167245#167245

Answer (score 4):

It's a linear combination of the support vectors where the coefficients are given by the Lagrange multipliers corresponding to these support vectors.