# Where does the definition of the hyperplane in a simple SVM come from?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, discriminant-analysis, geometry

I'm trying to figure out support vector machines using this [resource](http://www.tristanfletcher.co.uk/SVM%20Explained.pdf). On page 2 it is stated that for linearly separable data the SVM problem is to select a hyperplane such that $\vec{x}_i\vec{w} + b \geq 1$ for $y_i \in 1$ and $\vec{x}_i\vec{w} + b \leq -1$ for $y_i \in -1$. I'm having trouble to understand where the right-hand side of the constraints come from?

P.S The next question would be how to show that the SVM's margin is equal to $\frac{1}{||\vec{w}||}$.

Comment: See if you find this useful - http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43727/given-a-set-of-points-in-two-dimensional-space-how-can-one-design-decision-func/43811#43811

Comment: yes, the answer for this question is part of the answer given here http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/43811/16837

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially these two constraints basically require the training data to be correctly classified, and at least a certain distance from the decision threshold 0.  The hyperplane that fulfils these constraints with the smallest norm of the weights will have the maximal margin.  The value $\pm 1$ is essentially arbitrary, you could replace it with $\pm$ any value you like and it would merely rescale the coefficients of the hyper-plane, but without changing the decision boundary.  A value of 1 is used just to keep the maths neat.

Answer (score 2):

wx + b = -1 and wx + b = 1; These equations represent two parallel hyperplanes that are formed based on samples class (-1, +1). These two hyperplanes are used to optimize the distance between classes and to get optimal hyperplane. For optimization problem Lagrange multipliers are used.

[image]

You can find brief description on resources listed below.

---

Online course on Machine Learning by Andrew Ng is a great place to understand SVM and other ML algorithms: [Machine Learning - Andrew Ng](http://www.academicearth.org/courses/machine-learning/)
Hyperplane is thoroughly explained.

In order to better understand math behind the SVM, learning Optimization is the right choice. There is a great free ebook by S.Boyd: [Optimization - Boyd](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/)

Here you can find SVM papers: [svms.org/tutorials/](http://svms.org/tutorials/)